# Linux 13.04 Wired connection not automatically on

Tags: networking, broadcom

There is a direct LAN on my ThinkCenter Lenovo. At certain occasions it disconnects. Not all the time but mostly after a restart. It is simple to restart via: System Settings > Network > Wired...always works. There were no special drivers required during the initial installation. Is there a way to force a wired reconnect after a boot?

The LAN card is a Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02) and Linux 13.04

TIA
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System settings`> `Network` > `Wired` > click on the '`options`' below on the right side > a pop up window appear and check the '`connect automatically`' option.
[image]